# C# decimal.Parse() strange FormatException

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, cultureinfo, formatexception

There is `MyDataSet myDataSet` with `MyTable` with column `string MyNumber` (names changed). Then a row is added to the table (existing code):

```
decimal d = GetSum();
myDataSet.MyTable.AddMyTableRow(d.ToString("F2"));
```

Now I have to get that decimal number. But it throws `FormatException` when I try

```
decimal.Parse(myDataSet.MyTable[0].MyNumber);
// or
decimal.Parse(myDataSet.MyTable[0].MyNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//or
decimal.Parse(myDataSet.MyTable[0].MyNumber, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
//or
anything else..
```

Comment: What is the value of `myDataSet.MyTable[0].MyNumber` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: It looks like normal decimal value, like "1.23"
Now I think that maybe the problem is because of that "F2".. ?

Comment: Is it "like 1.23" or is it actually 1.23?

Comment: What data type is the MyNumber field? Are there any other fields are in the row? Can you give us examples of what exactly is in that field in row 0 when the exception is thrown?

Comment: @user646263 what are the character code points? is it perhaps not a `.` but some other character that looks like a `.` ?

Comment: @user646263 - Ideally you should use decimal.TryParse() in your code.

Comment: @Bibhu, why if you know its a decimal?

Comment: To get the code-points: `Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", s.Select(c => (int)c)));`, where `s` is the string - maybe `string s = myDataSet.MyTable[0].MyNumber;`

Comment: Please paste this line and post the result: (myDataSet.MyTable[0].MyNumber.ToList().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p, (int)p));

Comment: You can try: myDataSet.MyTable.AddMyTableRow(d.ToString("F2"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: What datatype is myDataSet?  Is it a standard "DataSet"?

Comment: try using the NumberFormatInfo class and pass as the Iformatprovider for the parse method.

Comment: Try to replace the full stop (.) with a comma (,) , if the conversion succeeds you know that you are still experiencing a culture issue.

Comment: something is going on with either your Data table or your string conversion.. This code works fine                       DataSet set = new DataSet();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add( new DataColumn("test", typeof(string)));
            set.Tables.Add(table);
            
            decimal d = 1.00M;
            set.Tables[0].Rows.Add(d.ToString("F2"));

            var val = decimal.Parse(set.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(val);

Comment: @David - yes it is actually 1.23 but a string.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - it is string field.

Comment: @ImGreg it is typed DataSet.

Comment: Also..
I am checking if it is not NullOrEmpty or DBNull..
When I create a new DataSet like @chriswarner and do the same decimal parsing then it is working correctly (or if I do it with strings only). Looks like there is a problem with the existing dataset, everything that goes through  that string field, cannot be parsed back.

Comment: What is the type of myDataSet.MyTable[0].MyNumber? decimal.Parse expects a string, so if you pass it any other type you would probably get a format exception. @user646263 – user65439 just now

Comment: Interesting that if I clone the DataTable and change the type of the Column to decimal, and then import a row in the new DataTable, I can get my decimal value from that new DataTable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating additional decimal columns for these numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue a few days back. This however was with my ModelBinding in a MVC project. I had to overwrite the class responsible for binding decimal values to model variables.

Try to replace the full stop (.) with a comma(,)

Comment: Replacing the full stop with a comma does not help (I checked, it really replaces)
Looks like I'll have to add a new decimal column..

Comment: What is the type of myDataSet.MyTable[0].MyNumber? decimal.Parse expects a string, so if you pass it any other type you would probably get a format exception. @user646263

Comment: It is a string. And the DataSet is typed.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that a FormatException suggests that you are not putting a string value into the Decimal.Parse method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cafs243z.aspx

The MSDN suggests that:

FormatException = s is not in the correct format.

From the looks you are accessing the column itself rather than the data contained in it.